# Unable to retrieve Dictionary value when used in LINQ

Tags: linq, dictionary, extension-methods, var

I am trying to update a 'Name' DataColumn based on a 'ID' DataColumn in a DataTable.
The 'ID'-'Name' pairs are stored in a Dictionary, which is created using a DataTable extension method as follows:

```
public static Dictionary<object, object> ToDictionary(this DataTable dataTable, string keyColumn, string valueColumn)
    {
        Dictionary<object, object> resultDict = new Dictionary<object, object>();

        if (dataTable.Columns.Contains(keyColumn) && dataTable.Columns.Contains(valueColumn))
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
                if (resultDict.ContainsKey(dr[keyColumn]) == false)
                    resultDict.Add(dr[keyColumn], dr[valueColumn]);
        }

        return resultDict;
    }
```

I am using the following LINQ syntax to update the DataColumn:

```
misUserDetailsDT.AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(row => row.SetField("DepartmentName", deptDict[row["DepartmentID"]].ToString()));
```

Here 'misUserDetailsDT' is the DataTable containing a filled column 'DepartmentID' and an empty column 'DepartmentName'-which I am trying to update.

I have a seperate method which generates the Dictionary as follows:

```
var deptDict = departmentDT.ToDictionary("DeptID", "DeptName");
```

where 'departmentDT' is a DataTable containing columns 'DeptID' and 'DeptName'.

Now when I execute the Linq code it give a 'KeyNotFoundException'. I have thoroughly checked that the 'departmentDT' table as well as 'deptDict' have all the keys(departmentIDs) from the 'misUserDetailsDT' table. Actually the 'departmentDT' itself has been generated from all the distinct IDs of 'misUserDetailsDT' table.

I think there is some issue with figuring out the appropriate type of the Dictionary keys. I even tried casting it to Int16, but it didn't work out.
Please help me figure out a solution.

Comment: `misUserDetailsDT.AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(row => row.SetField` is horribly inefficient. You have an in-memory object, a `DataTable`. Then you use `ToList` to create another in-memory object, a `List<DataRow>` which is nearly the same. The only reason is that you want to use `List.ForEach`. Why don't you use `foreach` in the first place on `DataTable.Rows`?

Comment: That was a very useful piece of info @TimSchmelter. I will definitely change the implementation as per your tip. However, I would want to understand why doesn't my implementation work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. The code works when dictionary values are casted to Int32. Thanks to @TimSchmelter for giving a very useful info. I will be changing the code to make use of foreach loop instead.